# What is the difference between xyz.domain.com and domain.com/xyz?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, web-applications, express, web-deployment

How do they differ in terms of backend/frontend architecture and implementation?
I know how to use `domain.com/xyz` where the page is rendered on the basis of information of `xyz`, how would that be done with `xyz.domain.com`

For example tumblr urls are like `username.tumblr.com`. How do they differ from, say, facebook pages where urls are like `facebook.com/username`?

Comment: xyz.domain.com is separeted (or service) resource (like translate.google.com or assets2.mysite.com), which can work without main resource. mysite.com/xyz is path of main resource with depends on main resource and assosiated with it

Comment: @itsnikolay what about, say, blogs where urls are like `xyz.tumblr.com`, how do they differe in implementation from say facebook pages where urls are like `facebook.com/xyz`?

Comment: xyz.tumblr.com (as i mean) shows that xyz is "like" nuclear site (for user which don't have knowledge to create site for yourself). facebook.com/xyz shows that the user is part of one big social network not a nuclear site.

Comment: @itsnikolay that's from a user's point of view. I was wondering how do they differ in terms of backend implementation.

Comment: For example we have separate appS for some domains (our editor stuff can create any domain they want). And we have a one separate app which handle many domains `domain.com` `anotherdomain.cz` and etc. It depend on your app purpose and point of user's view. (Users ever do not know that it is the just one app, they have different content (design and etc) on each domain). Rails gives any way to realize your business idea.

Answer (score 2):

## Domains

Domains are an autonomous administrative structure. Assets within the same organization can be compiled into a domain. Public facing domains (somehow, be it direct or through security measures) connect to the internet. They don't even need a web server.

```
tumblr         .com
------         ----
2nd level      TLD - Top level domain
domain
```

Anything after (to the left of) `tumblr` is what is called a sub-domain or lower level domain. Sub-domains represent a smaller autonomous administrative organization within the main domain, i.e. Microsoft has a HR department so `hr.microsoft.company` would be synonymous to this situation.

## Paths

`username` in `facebook.com/username` represents a path to a resource on the domain `facebook.com`, most likely (duh) on their webserver at port 80. I realize this is an oversimplification since Facebook probably uses a complex structure to deliver their content, but nevertheless, I'm hitting in the general area.

Going along with the HR analogy, they may maintain a series of forms for employees to access. Those would be stored as a resource rather than their own separate administrative structure.
`hr.microsoft.company/forms/i9_tax.form`

## The Difference

The difference between a path and a subdomain is that a path represents a resource on its domain's webserver, while a subdomain is content, either from the same web server or a different one from the 2nd level domain, but with it's own DNS record. A subdomain on the same web server as the 2nd level domain would be a "CNAME" (canonical name) record within the DNS database, while a completely difference web server would be an "A" (hostname/alias) record.

So `domain.com/index.html` points to the index.html file within domain.com's public html directory where as `xyz.domain.com` points to either the hostname of a completely different web server or to a directory within domain.com's file structure like domain.com/useassubdomain/xyz, but (again) with it's own DNS record. Both can be configured like any ole' webpage (as long as the servers running them support it).

A few reasons you would choose to utilize a subdomain over a resource of the original domain's subdirectories is because you want to:

- Distinguish regions or language (ja.wikipedia.org)
- Distinguish a branch with different goals than the larger organization (windowsupdate.microsoft.com)
- Sub-brands
- Delegate ownership or administration of content (including custom content like tumblr)